# Any idea on how to delete rows based on conditions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm new to R and I have been using the dplyr package to summarise. I couldn't figure out a solution to the following problem.

My tibble: 8 x 3 is as below:

```
df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 ),
                 block = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3), 
                 answer = "TRUE")
```

| id | block | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2 | TRUE |
| 2 | 3 | TRUE |

*ID -> participant ID*

*block -> highest correct block*

I want to retain only the **highest** block score for each participant but the highest block score is defined as the highest score with at least two correct (TRUE) in each block condition.

In the example above, the participant 1's highest block score would be 3 as there are at least two correct responses at block 3. The highest score for participant 2 is 2. See the example below.

The final output should be like this:

| id | block | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2 | TRUE |

Anyone has any idea on how I should start? Or any package that can solve this problem?

I managed to maintain the last row for each participant using the `slice_tail` argument but not sure how to proceed from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` to keep only those blocks that have `>= 2` `TRUE` values, later for each `id` keep the row with `max` `block` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, block) %>%
  filter(sum(as.logical(answer)) >= 2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(which.max(block)) %>%
  ungroup

#    id block answer
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#1     1     3 TRUE  
#2     2     2 TRUE
```

Comment: This works! Great  I'm not aware of the `as.logical` function in the base R.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id,block) %>%
  filter(answer == TRUE) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(block == max(block))

     id block answer
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1     3 TRUE  
2     2     2 TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion if you would like to use base R only.

```
s=lapply(1:nrow(df),
    function(x) 
      df[df$id==x, ][ as.vector(max(df[df$id==x, 'block'])==df[df$id==x, 'block']), ]
    )

ss=do.call(rbind.data.frame, s)
unique(ss)
```